# Service Bus for Windows Server High-Availability and Disaster Recovery

Tags: servicebus

We are currently implementing Service Bus for Windows Server in our solution, in order to replace MSMQ which offers limited disaster recovery options.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441405.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can create a new farm using the existing certificate or with a new certificate, or recover the storage layer by restoring SQL from backups and putting new SWBS nodes in a farm and connecting to this storage layer.

I'm not keen on (in the event of a disaster) building a new farm.

We have two datacentres (DC1 and DC2). Could we:

- Put two compute nodes in DC1 (Node1 and Node2), and one node in DC2 (Node3)? This will satisfy the SWBS requirement of at least 3 nodes for HA.
- Create an A record for our Farm DNS, and setup a load balancer in DC1 for this DNS name, that only points to Node1 and Node2 (so clients always connect to only those)?
- In the event that DC2 is lost (and as a result Node3), we'd be all good, since  Node1 and Node2 still provides HA, and the load balancer in DC1 still balances between these two

What would happen though, if we lost DC1? My initial idea is to change the A record for our Farm DNS to point to Node3. However, there will only be one node in the Farm (since Node1 and Node2 was lost with DC1). Will the service bus continue to operate, but just not have HA? Could I create multiple A records (one for the load balancer between Node1 and Node2, and one for Node3), and clients will alternate between the two?

PS: Our storage layer is handled by a SQL Availability Group, which has two (primary and secondary) nodes in DC1, and a third node (secondary as well) in DC2, so storage is covered

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is offtopic.

Comment: Of course. Doing both dev and infrastructure sometimes cause confusion.